# [React-Native]RN Version Upgrade Wiped Out Android Plugin Projects

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I was trying to upgrade my RN from 0.19 to 0.27 using the commands from the doc,

i.e.

npm install --save react-native@0.27

react-native upgrade (I chose the overwrite option when asked to update the latest RN files)

The npm install step worked fine but the upgrade step wiped out all my code in android plugin folders and any changes made to MainActivity.java. My environment is : MacOS, Genymotion, Android development

Thanks!

Comment: The best effort in this "accident" is to try `rnpm link` and hope it fixes the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You've missed that react-native upgrade asked you if you want to overwrite your files. `react-native upgrade` replaces your files with newer version if it's different than the default one. It does not merge your changes. Also jump from 0.19 to 0.27 is a big one so probably there was **a lot** of changes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, react-native upgrade will wipe everything out.  There's a command line option now (`react-native link`) that will put most of it back in, but not everything.

If you choose not to overwrite the files you are risking not including something very important and it may break the upgrade.

I don't know of a good way around this.  My process is to use a good ide that shows me exactly what has changed between upgrades.  Then I go though each change and see if I'm missing something.  The java code and android studio files tend to be quite easy.  But the xCode stuff is not, the pbxproj file is particularly awkward.  You mostly need to reconstruct it by using Xcode.  So... every time you do something to the xCode project, make a note of it! Yes this is a terrible solution, but I don't know what else to do.

I've ended up making detailed notes about everything I do during an upgrade.  And I upgrade recently because its easy to forget.